# Way to calculate how many partitions should assign?

Tags: apache-kafka

I would like to know what is the best way to calculate how many partitions I should assign for a topic?

For example, if I want to achieve handle 6k events per second for a topic, then how many partitions I should assign to it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create a topic with only one partition and do some performance testing to see how many events can be handled based on the existing hardware, say TPS1. Then the probably proper partition count is INT(6000 / TPS1).